# Timestamp in Sharepoint external content type not matching value in SQL table

Tags: bcs, sql-server, external-content-type

I have an external content type in SharePoint 2010 pulling data from a SQL 2008R2 DB using BCS. All the data comes back fine but the Time stamp column is off by 2 hours when I compare the values displayed in the Read List with the values returned when I query the DB in Management Studio. I've attached a picture with an example:

[image: Example]

The times displayed in the browser are 4 hours earlier than the Time stamp returned by Management Studio. I've checked the Date and Time settings on both the client and all the servers and they are fine. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Could we know the Timezones that each of the servers is in ?

Comment: Time zone is UTC -04:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2010/09/01/why-are-my-date-fields-wrong-in-business-connectivity-servces.aspx) seems to agree on my earlier comment, the interesting bit being:

> When you create an External Content Type and External List using the
>   SharePoint Designer, DateTime fields are normalized to UTC using the
>   NormalizeDateTime setting associated with the TypeDescriptor for the
>   DateTime field.

the fix being:

```
<TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.DateTime"  Name="DueDate" DefaultDisplayName="Due Date">  <Interpretation>   <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />  </Interpretation> </TypeDescriptor>
```

which you should add (or configure in SPD) to your bcs model.

**You do that by:**

1. Open the Site in SharePoint Designer
2. Select External Content Types from the Site Objects list
3. Find your ECT and select it
4. Click Export BDC Model
5. Export the file to your desktop
6. Open the File in Notepad or Visual Studio
7. Locate the TypeDescriptor for the DateTime field
8. Modify the  element as shown above
9. Save file on Desktop
10. Delete the ECT from SharePoint Designer
11. Close SharePoint Designer
12. Go to Central Administration site
13. Click Manage Service Applications
14. Click Business Data Connectity Service
15. Click Import to import the modified file

Comment: This seemed promising but it did not resolve my issue, I made the change to model but I still see the discrepancy

Comment: It must be related somehow, as your discrepancy is indeed the timezone difference. I saw other people reported that ot didn't work for them but I'd still check to see what SharePoint / SQL server consider the local timezone

Comment: I messed it up on the first attempt but this did do the trick

Comment: The links are now dead. How does one get to edit the BSC model in SPD to add the required tags?